# Generate DateRow for every row in a dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim diaryreader As SqlDataReader

diarycmd.CommandText = "dashboardusers"
diarycmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
diarycmd.Connection = usersconn
diaryconn.Open()
diaryreader = diarycmd.ExecuteReader()

Dim diaryTable As DataTable = New DataTable()

diaryTable.Load(diaryreader)


Dim dr As DataRow
for each (dr in diaryTable.rows)
Next
```

This is not working, I am getting a syntax error when i try to do for each dr in diarytable.rows

Comment: Why do you not directly return ds.Tables(0).rows() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get errors because your braces are set wrong. This would work:

```
Dim dr As DataRow
For Each dr In diaryTable.Rows
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use data table instead ? you will just have to iterate through the table

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)...
```

Comment: great idea could you go into more detail though

Comment: the reason is for each row in the datatable i want to put the fields in that row in separate labels

Comment: mfname.Text = dr("fname").ToString()
        mlname.Text = dr("lname").ToString()
        maddress.Text = dr("address").ToString()
        mcity.Text = dr("city").ToString()
        mstate.Text = dr("state").ToString()
        mzip.Text = dr("zip").ToString()

Comment: foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                someRandomComponent.Value = dr["YOUR_FIELD"].ToString();
                someOtherRandomComponent.Value = dr["YOUR_SECOND_FIELD"].ToString();
            }

Comment: each of those fields is a different column

Answer (score 0):

`ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count` retrieves the number of rows available in the DataTable. Then you can simply iterate over that count.

Comment: how would i iterate for the number in count on runtime